# react error unknown : TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: reactjs, runtime-error, react-state, react-state-management

i am getting data from api (i know api is working) and i am getting error (error is after my code)
i think error is because that in first place that code runs there is no "product.data.attributes.name" and that error create please help me!

```
const ProductDetails = () => {
const { params } = useRouteMatch();
const productCtx = useContext(ProductContext);
const [product,setProduct] = useState({});
const getProduct = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
        productCtx.toggleIsLoading()
        const response = await fetch(
            `http://localhost:1337/api/products/${params.id}?populate=*`,
            {
                method: "GET",
                headers : {
                    'content-type' : 'application/json'
                }
            })

        if (!response.ok) {
            console.log(response)
            throw new Error('Something went wrong!');
        }

        const data = await response.json();

        productCtx.toggleIsLoading()
        console.log(data.data.attributes.name);
        setProduct(data)
    }catch (error){
        console.log(error)
    }
},[])

useEffect(() => {
    getProduct()
},[getProduct])
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(product.data.attributes.name);
}, [product]);
return(
    <Fragment>
        <section className="single-product">
            <img src={product.img} alt={product.img} className="single-product-image"/>
            <article>
                <h1>{product.data.attributes.name}</h1>
                <h2>${product.data.attributes.price}</h2>
                <p>{product.data.attributes.description}</p>
            </article>
        </section>
    </Fragment>
);
```

}

this is the error

[this is the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkUIi.png)

Comment: you should only use one `useEffect` hook in a function component. 
And yes, `product` is an empty object at first render. try: `product.data && product.data.attributes.name`

Answer (score 0):

You can make render condition.

```
const ProductDetails = () => {
    const { params } = useRouteMatch();
    const productCtx = useContext(ProductContext);
    const [product,setProduct] = useState({});

    const getProduct = useCallback(async () => {
        try {
            productCtx.toggleIsLoading()
                const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:1337/api/products/${params.id}?populate=*`,
                {
                    method: "GET",
                    headers : {
                        'content-type' : 'application/json'
                    }
                })

            if (!response.ok) {
                console.log(response)
                throw new Error('Something went wrong!');
            }

            const data = await response.json();

            productCtx.toggleIsLoading()
            console.log(data.data.attributes.name);
            setProduct(data)
        } catch (error){
            console.log(error)
        }
    },[])

    useEffect(() => {
        getProduct()
    },[getProduct])

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(product.data.attributes.name);
    }, [product]);

    return(
        <Fragment>
            <section className="single-product">
                <img src={product.img} alt={product.img} className="single-product-image"/>
                <article>
                    <h1>{product.data?.attributes?.name || ''}</h1>
                    <h2>${product.data?.attributes?.price || ''}</h2>
                    <p>{product.data?.attributes?.description || ''}</p>
                </article>
            </section>
        </Fragment>
    );
}
```

Or You can make loading before `product.data` is available.

```
if(!product.data) return <div>Loading</div>

return(
        <Fragment>
            <section className="single-product">
                <img src={product.img} alt={product.img} className="single-product-image"/>
                <article>
                    <h1>{product.data?.attributes?.name || ''}</h1>
                    <h2>${product.data?.attributes?.price || ''}</h2>
                    <p>{product.data?.attributes?.description || ''}</p>
                </article>
            </section>
        </Fragment>
    );
}
```

Comment: tanks bro its working now